# Looping over multiple ranges in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, range

Currently I am trying to manually label some images for binary classification. I have divided up an image into patches, and connected them to a number from 0 to 255 (I have 256 patches per image). Now in certain patches, something interesting is happening and I would like to label those '1'. An example of patch ranges that I would like to label to 1 are; 121:124 and 137:140, 153:156.

Is there a way to loop over these ranges within a list so that I do not have to manually type such as in var image1? [121, 122, 123, 124, 137, 138, 139, 140, 153, 154, 155,156] ? The code I already have is below.

Thank you in advance!

```
def label_patch(image, patch_ranges):
    num_labels = np.arange((255))
    labels = []
    for patch, label in zip(image, num_labels):
        if label not in patch_ranges:
            labels.append(0)
        else:
            labels.append(1)
    return labels

image1 = label_patch(patched_imgs[1], [121, 122, 123, 124, 137, 138, 139, 140, 153, 154, 155,156])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to ease our efforts there, like so -

```
patch_ranges = np.r_[121:125, 137:141, 153:157]
```

Note that the ranges exclude the end value, hence the ending values are one more than the final intended values, i.e. `125, 141,` etc.

Furthermore, we could optimize on the code, to assign `1s`, like so -

```
image[np.isin(image, patch_ranges)] = 1
```

If the final output is to be categorized into `0s` and `1s` as seems to be the case, we can simply use the mask off `np.isin` to get the final output -

```
image1 = np.isin(image, patch_ranges).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you had in mind?

```
min_max_values = {121:124, 137:140, 153:156}
numbers = []
[numbers.extend(list(range(x,y))) for x,y in min_max_values.items()]
image1 = label_patch(patched_imgs[1], numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def label_patch_gen(*patch_ranges):
    """ Generator that yields True if a number is in one of the given ranges
    or False if not, for numbers from 0 to 255 """
    for n in range(256):
        yield any(start <= n <= stop for start, stop in patch_ranges)

def label_patch(*patch_ranges):
    """ Create a numpy array of 1s and 0s based on `label_patch_gen` """
    return np.array(list(label_patch_gen(*patch_ranges)), dtype=int)
```

You would then call it like this:

```
image1 = label_patch((121, 124), (137, 140), (153, 156))
```

Note there is no need to pass the actual image to the function, as you are returning a list of labels anyway.